# Progress filling an image with another image using JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx

I'm trying to fill an image progressively with another image using javaFX. The progress will vary from 0% to 100% depending on a variable fed from mysql so that when 100% is complete the first image will disappear.

The easiest way I can think of is creating an image for each 1%. But believe there is an easier way through code. Pleases help.

Could ImagePatern be used perhaps?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I think you can play with opacity ratio with two images
Eg.
image1.setOpacity(value1)  and image2.setOpacity(value2) in that value1 will be decreasing and value2 will be increasing. When value1 rached 0 image will be disappears.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I am after. Imagine a picture broken down into a grid. Each grid will fill up with corresponding part of new image. I.e.like the windows defrag tool if you know what I am talking abt.